# Increase badgevalue count using quickblox message push notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, chat, quickblox, badge

I am integrating Quickblox in my ios app for chatting . The problem facing in app is not increasing  badge count in background whenever chat notification appears Every time badge count showing 1.

And for sending chat I am using below code

```
    NSMutableDictionary *payload = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSMutableDictionary *aps = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [aps setObject:@"default" forKey:QBMPushMessageSoundKey];
    [aps setObject:@"1" forKey:QBMPushMessageBadgeKey];
    [aps setObject:@"helo second chat" forKey:QBMPushMessageAlertKey];
    [payload setObject:aps forKey:QBMPushMessageApsKey];

    QBMPushMessage *pushMessage = [[QBMPushMessage alloc] initWithPayload:payload];
    [QBMessages TSendPush:pushMessage toUsers:@"112345" delegate:self];
```

Comment: Push notification never increment the badge they just override it. Thus unless Quickblox is keep track of the badge number the app will just show the badge number that is set, I you case `1`.